# trouble getting posted values in php

Tags: php, forms, post

This is a post notification sending me data in text/xml.  I have no problem getting the posted xml, but how do I get the values of `X-Security-Data` and `X-Security-Hash`?

I am used to using $_POST and $_GET, but in this case I am using `$xml_post = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));` to get the xml... what about the other two values?

```
X-Security-Data:1409261330848SEN140826-7569-89111S
X-Security-Hash:c063d68a6112dbc15e3eccf4943879b0
User-Agent:FS
Content-Length:584
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Host:www.test.com

<subscription > 
    <enddate></enddate> 
    <nextperioddate>2015-08-26T00:00:00+0000</nextperioddate> 
    <periodcount>1</periodcount> 
    <test>true</test> 
    <quantity>10</quantity> 
    <reference>some reference</reference> 
    <customerurl>some url</customerurl> 
    <customer> 
        <fname>some name</fname> 
        <lname>some name</lname> 
        <company>some company</company> 
        <phone>11112223333</phone> 
        <email>test@test.com</email> 
    </customer> 
</subscription>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: Thanks... that pointed me in the right direction.  After some more reading... any reason to use this method instead of something like `$_SERVER['X-Security-Hash']`? One better than the other in some way?

Comment: that'd work too. no idea if php will always guarantee that all request headers show up in $_SERVER, or it's just been assumed until now. at least with the getallheaders query, you're getting it directly from Apache, with minimal mediation by php.

Comment: Well using $_SERVER didn't work so I tried getallheaders and used its array - worked great.  Thanks again Marc